# Sort an array based on a calculation that uses data from two other array's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

I am developing a website/blog/film reviewing site using React.

I have implemented basic sorting functionality. A user can sort by a single field (e.g. `myRating`, `position`, `imdbAvgRating`, `imdbNumVotes`).

For example, the following JavaScript code sorts my list in ascending order of the `position` field (i.e. low pos -> high pos)

```js
__filtered_data: Array.from(this.props.filmReviewsWebdata)
    .sort((a,b) => { return a['position'] - b['position'] })
    .reverse(),
```

Currently, I am trying to implement a way for the user to sort based on a calculation that requires data from two separate lists...

The calculation is simply
`myRating - imdbAvgRating`

This is problematic because I am getting each of these from two separate sources:

- `imdbAvgRating` is a property of `this.props.filmReviewsWebdata`, `imdbAvgRating`
- `myRating` is a property of `this.props.filmReviewsLocaldata`

(I have these separate because I don't want to hard code data that I can just pull from an API)

From my perspective there are 3 options...

1. Iterate both lists simultaneously, like some kind of zip functionality in python?

   ```js
   __filtered_data: zip(Array.from(this.props.filmReviewsWebdata), Array.from(filmReviewsLocaldata))
       .sort((a,b,c,d) => { return (a['myRating'] - c['imdbAvgRating']) - (b['myRating'] - d['imdbAvgRating']) })
       .reverse(),
   ```

   (no idea what I'm doing here)
2. A nested sorting function?

   ```js
   __filtered_data: Array.from(this.props.filmReviewsWebdata)
       .sort((a,b) => {
           Array.from(this.props.filmReviewsLocaldata)
               .sort((c,d) => {
                   if (a['letterboxdFilmId'] == c['letterboxdFilmId']) {
                       return (a['myRating'] - c['imdbAvgRating']) - (b['myRating'] - d['imdbAvgRating'])
                   }
               })
       })
   ```

   (no idea what I'm doing here either)
3. Perhaps I should create `__merged_data` state variable that literally just iterates over the two lists prior to anything and just merges matching objects, this would remove the need to iterate over two lists simultaneously, and then all the data required for the calculation is in one object...

   But ideally it would be nice to somehow use a zip function and `Array.sort()` in conjunction...

I am still learning the ropes of React and JavaScript. The answer may be simpler than I'm imagining, so any JavaScript wisdom from the stack overflow gurus would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: reading the problem my first thought was your option 3, it would be easy to maintain and the performance would be better if you don't need to recreate the __merged_data every time you need to sort.

Comment: Yeah in retrospect iterating two lists containing hundreds of objects and comparing each object and doing the calculation, every time a user selects that sorting type, wouldn't be great for performance... Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Could you share an example structure of both `filmReviewsWebdata` and `filmReviewsLocaldata`? How do you know which `filmReviewsWebdata` belongs to which `filmReviewsLocaldata`? Do they share the same array index? Do they share the same identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two datasets by the unique identifier. Basic idea:

```js
const filmReviewsWebdata = [{
    id: 123,
    imdbAvgRating: 5
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    imdbAvgRating: 4
  },
    {
    id: 456,
    imdbAvgRating: 4
  },
]

const filmReviewsLocaldata = [
  {
    id: 123,
    myRating: 5
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    myRating: 4
  },
]

const mappedById = filmReviewsLocaldata.reduce((acc, film) => {
  acc[film.id] = film;
  return acc;
}, {});

const combined = filmReviewsWebdata.map( film => ({...film, ...mappedById[film.id] }));

console.log(combined);
```

If you do not want to combine you can just keep them separate and reference the mapped object in the sort by the id.

Comment: Ah this is interesting! I'll experiment with this, thanks for the advice.